# Visual studio installer needs windows 10..is there a way around without updating my OS(windows 7)?

Tags: visual-studio, windows-7, windows-10

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D6JX9.png) I want to avoid updating my current OS. The installer says I need windows 10 so I'm tempted to download the lso and see, but it is a pretty big download. I am trying to install visual studio 2013

Comment: Which Visual Studio do you want to install? Add more details

Comment: Well, that is wrong, I don't know what installer is telling you that. Visual Studio 2015 will run on Windows 7 SP1 and later. [System Requirements](https://www.visualstudio.com/visual-studio-2015-system-requirements-vs)

Comment: I assume you are running Windows 7. VS 2013 probably requires SP1, also. Have you installed that? When you click on the link in the setup window, what does it say?

Comment: I added a screenshot of what the setup says, 'This version of Visual Studio requires a newer version of Windows', and I'm running windows 7 Ultimate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if your Windows 7 is Windows 7 SP 1. Prerequisite:

```
Express for Windows Desktop (Windows Programs) - Windows 7 SP1 (With IE 10)
```

You may check if you have SP1 as described [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/2352.how-to-check-if-service-pack-one-for-windows-7-is-installed-or-not.aspx) (by going to the System).

If you do not have the SP1, you may go and install it manually from [Windows Download Center](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/install-windows-7-service-pack-1).